# Filtering pivot table columns, only count if

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I was wondering if it's possible to filter a single pivot table column in excel.
In other words, when you summarize the data **by count**, that the data for a certain column is only counted if it has a certain value.

I know that it's possible to get these values by report filtering, but then I need a separate pivot table for the values I don't want to be filtered.  Also, some values are 0 and thus are not displayed if report-filtered. Changing the option to display 0 values doesn't change anything. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can add a filter to a pivot report by selecting a cell that borders the table (but is outside the pivot area) and choosing *Filter* from the *Data* tab.

To add a filter to just the *Count Of* column select the cell above and the cell containing the title and then choose the *Filter* option from the menus as shown...

[image]

To only count data if it fulfills a certain condition, I think you would need to add another column called OK to the source data, with a formula like `IF(Status="OK",1,0)`. Then add this to the pivot table layout. [Note: there is a calculated field option for pivot tables but it only seems to work as you would expect if data is displayed - in this case status would need to be showing.]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm searching how to filter the count creteria themselves. Like in the picture, the last column in the pivot table should only count the values with 'OK' in the Status-column of the database. **Picture link** : [Pivot Table](https://www.dropbox.com/s/06sx5wxwhvtls0p/pivottable.jpg).

Comment: Ok, that wasn't too clear from your original question. I think you would need to add another column called `OK` to the source data, with a formula like `IF(Status="OK",1,0)`. Then add this to the pivot table layout. [Note: there is a calculated field option for pivot tables but it only seems to work as you would expect if data is displayed - in this case status would need to be showing.]

Comment: Yup, that's probably my best shot. Thanks alot !

Comment: What about if you cannot modify data source? Is it possible to solve the problem in pivot table itself? I tried to add calculated field like `=IF(Status="OK",1,0)` but Excel ain't that stupid to swallow that.

Comment: *Filter* button is grayed on my Excel.

Comment: I've been looking for an answer to this problem for years! I never would have thought of this simple solution! Brilliant!

Answer (score 5):

That's not working on my Excel 365.  Try selecting the 1st field on the first row then:

- r-click
- filter
- value filters...

Comment: This worked for me. Filter on the columns in the Rows section of the Pivot Table, then you can select the "Count of..." field to filter on.

Comment: Unlike some of the alternatives I have seen, this also impacts the grand total row.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

1. Left click on any row items drop-down carrot
2. Click 'value filter'
3. Choose value filter ('equals', 'greater than', etc)
4. Choose value field item you'd like it to filter on (eg 'count of days' from the image i can see in the original question)

You can also do it via the right click options as @kztd mentioned